# Difficulty understanding the Taylor expansion of a function.

Tags: taylor-expansion

I believe I have somewhat of an understanding of the Taylor expansion:

$$
f(a)+{\frac{f^{\prime}(a)}{1!}}(x-a)+{\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(a)}{2!}}(x-a)^{2}+{\frac{f^{\prime\prime\prime}(a)}{3!}}(x-a)^{3}+\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}}(x-a)^{n}.
$$

First you get the value of the function at a particular point, and then add the derivatives of increasing orders with n-th order of the point.

Then, how does the author derive at the Equation 1.10 in the excerpt here where he derives the expansion for the function $\Delta P_{\Gamma} (\omega)$?

The excerpt is copied as follows:

---

The laser frequency $\omega_{\mathrm{L}}$ is modulated at the modulation frequency $\Omega$, which changes $\omega_{\mathrm{L}}$ periodically from $\omega_{\mathrm{L}}-\Delta \omega_{\mathrm{L}} / 2$ to $\omega_{\mathrm{L}}+\Delta \omega_{\mathrm{L}} / 2$. When the laser is tuned through the absorption spectrum, the difference $\Delta P_{\mathrm{T}}=P_{\mathrm{T}}\left(\omega_{\mathrm{L}}-\Delta \omega_{\mathrm{L}} / 2\right)-$ $P_{\mathrm{T}}\left(\omega_{\mathrm{L}}+\Delta \omega_{\mathrm{L}} / 2\right)$ is detected with a lock-in amplifier (phase-sensitive detector) tuned to the modulation frequency $\Omega$ (Fig. 1.4). If the modulation sweep $\Delta \omega_{\mathrm{L}}$ is sufficiently small, the first term of the Taylor expansion
$$
\Delta P_{\mathrm{T}}(\omega)=\frac{\mathrm{d} P_{\mathrm{T}}}{\mathrm{d} \omega} \Delta \omega_{\mathrm{L}}+\frac{1}{2 !} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 P_{\mathrm{T}}}{\mathrm{d} \omega^2} \Delta \omega_{\mathrm{L}}^2+\ldots,
$$
is dominant. This term is proportional to the first derivative of the absorption spectrum $\alpha(\omega)=\frac{\Delta P(\omega)}{P_0 L}$ as can be seen from (1.1b): when $P_0=P_{\mathrm{R}}$ is independent of $\omega$ we obtain
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} \alpha(\omega)}{\mathrm{d} \omega}=-\frac{1}{P_{\mathrm{R}} L} \frac{\mathrm{d} P_{\mathrm{T}}}{\mathrm{d} \omega} .
$$

---

I am stuck in understanding the how the equation for $\Delta P_{\Gamma}(\omega)$ is derived below.

[first part of the excerpt](https://i.imgur.com/rtRSmRq.png)

[second part of the excerpt](https://i.imgur.com/y62YRCc.png)

How does he exactly derive the Taylor expansion?